# Python Rich Live not working in Intellij IDE

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, rich

I have the following example of Rich Live from the official examples of Rich. ([layout.py](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/blob/master/examples/layout.py))

**Code**

```
from datetime import datetime

from time import sleep

from rich.align import Align
from rich.console import Console
from rich.layout import Layout
from rich.live import Live
from rich.text import Text

console = Console()
layout = Layout()

layout.split(
    Layout(name="header", size=1),
    Layout(ratio=1, name="main"),
    Layout(size=10, name="footer"),
)

layout["main"].split_row(Layout(name="side"), Layout(name="body", ratio=2))

layout["side"].split(Layout(), Layout())

layout["body"].update(
    Align.center(
        Text(
            """This is a demonstration of rich.Layout\n\nHit Ctrl+C to exit""",
            justify="center",
        ),
        vertical="middle",
    )
)


class Clock:
    """Renders the time in the center of the screen."""

    def __rich__(self) -> Text:
        return Text(datetime.now().ctime(), style="bold magenta", justify="center")


layout["header"].update(Clock())

with Live(layout, screen=True, redirect_stderr=False) as live:
    try:
        while True:
            sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

**Problem**

This works as expected when I do python layout.py in Powershell.
But if I click on run via the IntelliJ IDE it is not working.

The following is my configuration
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toggling the "Emulate terminal in output console" option in the Run configuration should fix the problem.
If this option is unavailable in the run configuration, remove it from **Run | Edit Configuration** and create a new one by right-clicking the file in the editor, **More Run/Debug | Modify Configuration**.
Also, the version of IDEA is a bit outdated; please consider updating to the latest.